Removing the password from the XL CLI config.yaml
I'm using the XL CLI in Linux.  The config.yaml wants a password, but that won't meet our standards.
I tried "prompt" and just leaving password blank, as well as removing password completely.
I noticed that the blueprint.yaml has a way to prompt for missing parameters.  Does anyone know a way to get config.yaml to behave similarly?

There is no inherent prompt functionality, but you can achieve the result you want with a short wrapper file such as:
read -s -p "password: " PW
xl --xl-release-password $PW "$@"

